# Dynamic Nested Arrays in Python - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project that requires dynamically creating and populating nested arrays in Python. But there is an error, and I can't find the issue in my code.

```
def pop_array(rows, cols):
    ar = [[]]

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            ar[i][j] = i + j

    return ar

rows = 3
cols = 4
result = pop_array(rows, cols)
print(result)
```

I want to create a 2D array with the specified number of rows and columns and populate it with some values. However, the code is giving me an out of range error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: `ar[i]` will fail for any `i>0`, because `ar` contains only a single empty list. So `ar[i][j]` will fail too.

Comment: you have to init your 'ar' with the required number of nested arrays: ar = [[] for _ in range(rows)] and then fill each array in the loop: ar[i].append(i + j)

Comment: You are not working with an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but with a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). These are two different things in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write ar = [[]], you create a list containing one empty list.

So, when you later try to access ar[i][j], you encounter an IndexError because ar[i] is an empty list, and you can't access an element at index j within an empty list.

Try this:

```
def pop_array(rows, cols):
    ar = [[0] * cols for _ in range(rows)]

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            ar[i][j] = i + j

    return ar

rows = 3
cols = 4
result = pop_array(rows, cols)
print(result)
```